# Is there a word for something done to you because you did it to someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I was wondering because when coming across videos about people who went to jail for abuse and murder, comments will say they should have to go through the same thing they inflicted on the other person. Even with the death penalty being a thing, the torture penalty sounds weird.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127900/discussion-on-question-by-user2459-is-there-a-word-for-something-done-to-you-bec).

Answer (score 1):

Another instance being the, almost petty, expression '**tit-for-tat**'. This expression is defined, by Google, as a **noun** and means: the infliction of an injury or insult in return for one that one has suffered, i.e. "as we struggled for those last two votes, the tit for tat continued."

Also, tit-for-tat can be used in a sentence, e,g, "I noticed she didn't send me a card - I think it was **tit for tat** because I forgot her birthday last year" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tit-for-tat

There may be additional discussion as to whether one shoud write the hyphenated 'tit-for-tat' or simply tit for tat.

Answer (score 1):

Some might call it ...

[***Karma***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma)

> The idea of karma originated in Indian religions such as Hinduism and Buddhism, but is also used in the West to mean that good deeds will be rewarded with good results, with the opposite for bad deeds. This assumption is captured in the popular saying “What goes around comes around” and in the much older proverb “As you sow, so shall you reap.”

As noted in *Psychology Today*, Americans often say:

[***What goes around comes around.***](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/hot-thought/201307/karma-what-goes-around-comes-around)

Both suggest a type of philosophy that indicates an unavoidable retribution for wrong past deeds...

---

Comments are locked. These ideas are not exactly unique. It should not be necessary to post links and citations to such obvious ideas, but I did.. I will leave this up for a while, then maybe delete and vote to close for SWR issues.

Comment: It's a new world ladies and gentlemen. Comments are not answers, but answers can be comments...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but it reminds me of [Hammurabi's code from the Mesopotamian Empire.](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Hammurabi) That's where the idea "An eye for an eye" comes from.

> The great Code of Hammurabi is often said to have been based on the principle of “an eye for an eye, a tooth for a tooth,” as if this were some fundamental principle of justice, elaborated and applied to all cases.

Also see: [Code of Hammurabi](https://www.history.com/topics/ancient-history/hammurabi)

Comment: Actually, an "eye for an eye" is a phrase that comes from the Levitical law of the ancient Israelites -- Leviticus 24:19-20.

Comment: So you edited your answer, in a post that was from 5+ months ago. I don't remember what you said, so I don't know if your edit was substantial or not (neither can I view your edits). So yeah. Also there's the claim that the idea came from your source, which you don't demonstrate that it does. (Prehistory dating is an inexact science to put it mildly, and if true, does not prove influence or causation). Yet you don't want to be "dragged into" theological debates! Uhm, ok, bro. Whatevs.

Comment: @FeliniusRex It was not the OP who edited anything....

Comment: @FeliniusRex You can view the edit trail at the link in the answer's footer - click on ["edited <time> ago"](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/561177/revisions) above the editor's name.

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of a "**reciprocation**" is "a return in kind or like value". However, I'm not sure you'll be satisfied with this, as it doesn't specifically signify that the initiating act caused harm to the person reciprocating it.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocation

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to find one single word which can mean requital or retribution, but of a negative kind and inflicting the same pain. A more informal phrase which means exactly that is:

***get even***

> to punish someone who has done something bad to you by doing something
> equally bad to that person ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-even))

e.g.

> Don't get angry, get even. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-even))

A formal phrase is ***retributive justice***:

> *Retributive justice* is a theory of punishment that when an offender breaks the law, justice requires that they suffer in return, and that ***the response to a crime is proportional to the offence***. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retributive_justice))